# Is there a printing standard for acceptance of proof to printed material?

Tags: print-design, print-production, proofing

I couldnt find if the acceptance rate is 90 to 95% color difference of print versus proof. I need an industry document to use a reference.

Comment: You could ask your print provider. But perhaps you are looking for the ISO standard for proof printing? [ISO 12647-7:2016](https://www.iso.org/standard/66426.html)

Comment: what would % of a color difference mean in unambiguous scientific terms?

Comment: What is the acceptable industry standard in terms of fidelity of the final printed sheet to the client approved digital proof. Grade % 85-90 closeness to proof?

Comment: I don't think color difference is often measured in %. It's quite complicated. There is a Wikipedia article about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference).